# Query params not updating in controller

Tags: ember.js

Using build v1.5.0-beta.4

My query params are showing up in the router in the params.queryParams object but do not seem to be updating their respective properties in the controller. Can't tell if this is a bug or behaving as expected. If this is behaving as expected, what flag do I need to set to get the desired behavior like in the older builds?

Could someone take a look at this jsbin http://jsbin.com/tojamara/64/edit and see if this is a bug or not?

If I change the build to the ones used in the documentation it behaves as expected. See 
http://jsbin.com/tojamara/66/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's that version of Ember, use a canary build (1.6+).