# Binding model changes to view in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to implement an interface for a logger with EmberJS and has been great but I run into an wall.

Currently I have the following code:

logs.hbs

```
...
{{input action="search" onEvent="keypress" value=searchText class="search" placeholder="Search"}}
...
<table id="log" class="log">
    <thead>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>End Time</th>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Method</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Response Code</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{render "dashboard/logTableLine" model}}
    </tbody>
</table>
...
```

logTableLine.hbs

```
{{#each model}}
    {{#link-to "dashboard.log" _id tagName="tr"}}
        <td>{{ServiceID}}</td>
        <td>{{DateString StartTime}}</td>
        <td>{{DateString EndTime}}</td>
        <td>{{URL}}</td>
        <td>{{Method}}</td>
        <td>{{AuthName Auth}}</td>
        <td>{{StatusCode}}</td>
    {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

and my app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true
});

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource("dashboard", { path: "/" }, function(){
        this.route("logs", { path: "/logs" });
        this.route("log", { path: "/logs/log/:_id" });
    });
});

App.DashboardLogsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return Ember.$.getJSON("/logs.json");
    },
    actions: {
        search: function(value){
            if(value != '')
                this.set("content", Ember.$.getJSON("/logs.json?search=" + value));
        }
    }
});

App.DashboardLogRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return Ember.$.getJSON("/logs/log/" + params._id + ".json");
    }
});
```

My problem is binding that model to the view, so that after the search call to the server the view rerenders. I want to search all data, not only what I have in the interface (last 100 records).

So, first question: why the view isn't updating (binded) to the model?
Second: Is there a better way (best pratice) to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're implementing search without triggering a re-route.  So if the user searched and then wanted to go back to the page before they were at before they searched, they would have no way to do that.  What you want to do is re-route the user to the same page, but pass in query parameters.  Then in the model function you can see what parameters were passed in and fetch the data accordingly.  Ember's latest and greatest way of doing this is the query-params feature: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/ It's been in the works for a while and is now in beta.  I'd give it a go, because it's a really clean, intuitive way of solving this problem.  Good luck!

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help. I did follow your advice and following this example: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/3008/edit I changed my code, it's practically the same has the example, my variables are working fine but the url isn't updating. My code: http://jsbin.com/zuholano/1/edit Note: the console.log displays the correct value for the variable aka the changes that I input to the search.

Comment: My ember version is 1.6.0... So.. not the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429099/query-params-not-updating-in-controller

Comment: Added new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884927/query-params-not-updating-url-or-triggering-model-refresh-in-emberjs-1-6-0