# Query-params not updating URL or triggering model refresh in EmberJS 1.6.0

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to develop a search feature for a log list interface in EmberJS using query-params but I can't get it to work.
Based on this example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ucanam/2708/edit I have:

```
App.DashboardLogsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
        search: {
            refreshModel: true
        }
    },
    model: function(params){
        console.log(params.search)
        if(params.search && params.search != '')
            return Ember.$.getJSON("/logs.json?search=" + params.search);
        else
            return Ember.$.getJSON("/logs.json");
    },
    actions: {
        queryParamsDidChange: function(){
            this.refresh();
        }
    }
});
App.DashboardLogsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    queryParams: ["search"],
    search: null,
    searchText: Ember.computed.oneWay("search"),
    actions: {
        search: function(){
            this.set("search", this.get("searchText"));
            console.log(this.get("search"))
        }
    }
});
```

The console.log(this.get("search")) displays the changes that I submit on my input but neither the URL is updated, neither the model is refreshed... I'm missing something?

Comment: I think the query params are not available by default on 1.6.0. Now they are only available on the beta builds 1.7.x-beta

Comment: Or you could probably enable them by adding the flag `ENV = {FEATURES: {'query-params-new': true}};`

Comment: I already tried to manual enable the query-params feature, didn't work...

Comment: Updating EmberJS to 1.7.0 beta2 solved the problem without changing a  period. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queryParams are only fully implemented in the current beta. For more information, see [the current documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/)

Comment: Didn't see that big and fat "WARNING: query params are only available in recent beta builds of Ember.".
Was going to swear that that wasn't there... :P Thanks...